# Как вывести QTreeView в QMainWindow окне?

Tags: python-3.x, qt, pyqt5

не могу понять как прикрутить в "окно" (QMainWindow) элемент QTreeView, почему то оно попросту не прорисовывается и при этом вызывает предупреждение:

> QLayout: Attempting to add QLayout "" to addTaskWindow "", which already has a layout

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QPushButton, QTreeView, QVBoxLayout, QGroupBox
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QStandardItemModel


class addTaskWindow(QMainWindow):
    dataView = None
    layout = None
    FROM, SUBJECT, DATE = range(3)
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        #flags = []
        super(addTaskWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.title = 'PyQt5 simple window - pythonspot.com'
        self.left = 10
        self.top = 10
        self.width = 640
        self.height = 480
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.dataGroupBox = QGroupBox("Inbox")
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('play.png'))
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.initSubmitBtn()
        self.initListBox()

    def initSubmitBtn(self):
        self.pushButton = QPushButton(QIcon('play.png'), "Запустить", self)
        self.pushButton.resize(200, 50)
        self.pushButton.move(120,300)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.onSubmit)

    def initListBox(self):
        self.dataView = QTreeView()
        #self.layout.addWidget(self.dataView)
        #self.dataView.setRootIsDecorated(False)
        #self.dataView.setAlternatingRowColors(True)
        model = self._createModel(self)
        self.addData(model, 'service@github.com', 'Your Github Donation','03/25/2017 02:05 PM')
        self.addData(model, 'support@github.com', 'Github Projects','02/02/2017 03:05 PM')
        self.addData(model, 'service@phone.com', 'Your Phone Bill','01/01/2017 04:05 PM')
        self.dataView.setModel(model)
        #self.dataView.resize(200, 400)
        self.dataView.setFixedSize(443, 310)
        #mainLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        #mainLayout.addWidget(self.dataView)


    def _createModel(self,parent):
            model = QStandardItemModel(0, 3, parent)
            model.setHeaderData(self.FROM, Qt.Horizontal, "From")
            model.setHeaderData(self.SUBJECT, Qt.Horizontal, "Subject")
            model.setHeaderData(self.DATE, Qt.Horizontal, "Date")
            return model

    def addData(self,model, mailFrom, subject, date):
        model.insertRow(0)
        model.setData(model.index(0, self.FROM), mailFrom)
        model.setData(model.index(0, self.SUBJECT), subject)
        model.setData(model.index(0, self.DATE), date)


    def onSubmit(self):
        self.hide()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте `self.setCentralWidget(self.dataView)` чтобы централизовать виджет в окне `mainwindow`

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QPushButton, QTreeView, QVBoxLayout, QGroupBox, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QStandardItemModel


class addTaskWindow(QMainWindow):
    dataView = None
    layout = None
    FROM, SUBJECT, DATE = range(3)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        #flags = []
        super(addTaskWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.title = 'PyQt5 simple window - pythonspot.com'
        self.left = 10
        self.top = 10
        self.width = 640
        self.height = 480
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.dataGroupBox = QGroupBox("Inbox")
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('play.png'))
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.initSubmitBtn()
        self.initListBox()

    def initSubmitBtn(self):
        self.pushButton = QPushButton(QIcon('play.png'), "Запустить", self)
        self.pushButton.resize(200, 50)
        self.pushButton.move(120,300)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.onSubmit)

    def initListBox(self):
        self.dataView = QTreeView()
        #self.layout.addWidget(self.dataView)
        #self.dataView.setRootIsDecorated(False)
        #self.dataView.setAlternatingRowColors(True)
        model = self._createModel(self)
        self.addData(model, 'service@github.com', 'Your Github Donation','03/25/2017 02:05 PM')
        self.addData(model, 'support@github.com', 'Github Projects','02/02/2017 03:05 PM')
        self.addData(model, 'service@phone.com', 'Your Phone Bill','01/01/2017 04:05 PM')
        self.dataView.setModel(model)
        #self.dataView.resize(200, 400)
        self.dataView.setFixedSize(443, 310)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.dataView)
        #mainLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        #mainLayout.addWidget(self.dataView)


    def _createModel(self,parent):
            model = QStandardItemModel(0, 3, parent)
            model.setHeaderData(self.FROM, Qt.Horizontal, "From")
            model.setHeaderData(self.SUBJECT, Qt.Horizontal, "Subject")
            model.setHeaderData(self.DATE, Qt.Horizontal, "Date")
            return model

    def addData(self,model, mailFrom, subject, date):
        model.insertRow(0)
        model.setData(model.index(0, self.FROM), mailFrom)
        model.setData(model.index(0, self.SUBJECT), subject)
        model.setData(model.index(0, self.DATE), date)


    def onSubmit(self):
        self.hide()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = addTaskWindow()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```